# O/R mapping tools ASP

Tags: orm, asp-classic

Are there O/R mapping tools for ASP (not ASP.NET) and are these useful in ASP?

Lieven Cardoen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick scan a google search and i don't see anything that states classic ASP. Given the somewhat dated platform that ASP is, i doubt any major players would appear in that space.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own a few years ago - it does not bother traversing relationships, but abstracts away data reads and writes very nicely.